# calculate the percent instead the sum

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Actually my function calculate the sum of all same keys in each object

```
const arr = [{id:1, "my color":1,"my fruit":4},{id:2,"my color":2,"my fruit":4}];

const res = arr.reduce((a, { id, ...rest }) => {
  Object.entries(rest).forEach(([key, val]) => {
    a[key] = (a[key] || 0) + val;
  });
  return a;
}, {});

result is >> [{"my color":3,"my fruit":8}
```

I'd like to get their percent (value/sum of values) and not instead their sum, like this

`{ "my color": 27, "my fruit": 73 }`

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Please can you explain a bit more.

Comment: In your result, add up all the values. Then change each value to `value * 100 / sum`. Basic math.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following

```js
var obj = {"my color":3,"my fruit":8};
var total = Object.values(obj).reduce((a,c) => a+c, 0);
Object.keys(obj).forEach(k => obj[k] = Math.round(obj[k]*100/total));
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well just sum up all values first, then divide each entry by that:

```
// Sum up all properties with same key
const sum = { };

for(const entry of array) {
  for(const [key, value] of Object.entries(entry)) {
     sum[key] = (sum[key] || 0) + value;
  }
}

// Map the array to an array of percentages   
const percentage = array.map(entry => {
  const result = {};
  for(const [key, value] of Object.entries(entry)) {
     result[key] = value / sum[key] * 100;
  }
  return result;
});
```